# Button Rotate GPUImage

Tags: rotation, gpuimage

I want to build a button that every time you press rotates the image by 90 °. I tried to do so, but it does not work

```
 (IBAction)Rotate:(id)sender {
    staticPictureOriginalOrientation=UIImageOrientationLeft;
    [self.imageView setInputRotation:staticPictureOriginalOrientation atIndex:0];
    [staticPicture addTarget:filter];
    [staticPicture processImage];
}
```

what I get is this

Tap Button +90° rotate image and processImage

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same thing using this code:

```
selectedFilter = [[GPUImageTransformFilter alloc] init];

[(GPUImageTransformFilter *)selectedFilter setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((M_PI)*0.5)];

self.img = [selectedFilter imageByFilteringImage:self.img];
self.mainImage.image = self.img;
self.originalImage = self.img;
```